Change font color of Tab component in NextJS
I'm working on a Next.js project using NextUI for components and Tailwind CSS for styling. I've been trying to customize the text color of the  component within a vertical  setup. Specifically, I want the text to appear as dark-orange in dark mode. However, my attempts with Tailwind's utility classes like dark:text-dark-orange haven't worked.
Here's my code:
`
    <Tabs radius={"none"} isVertical={isVertical} aria-label="Options">
                                <Tab className="text-dark-blue" title="Website ">
                                    <Card className="py-4 bg-red-950 ">
                                        <CardBody className="overflow-visible py-2">
                                            <Image alt="Card background" className="object-cover rounded-xl" src="https://nextui.org/images/hero-card-complete.jpeg" width={270} height={0} />
                                        </CardBody>
                                        <CardHeader className="pb-0 pt-2 px-4 flex-col items-start">
                                            <h4 className="font-bold text-large">Frontend Radio</h4>
                                            <small className="text-default-500">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</small>
                                        </CardHeader>
                                    </Card>
    </Tabs>

`

tailwind.config.js:
`

    const { nextui } = require("@nextui-org/theme");
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
        darkMode: "class",
        content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/components/(navbar|tabs).js"],
        theme: {
            extend: {
                backgroundImage: {
                    "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
                    "gradient-conic": "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
                },
                fontFamily: {
                    nexa: "nexa",
                },
                colors: {
                    "dark-blue": "#101825",
                    "dark-orange": "#e76928",
                },
            },
        },
        plugins: [nextui()],
    };
`


Return an object as the title prop on your Tag instead of a string.  Then you can add any styles you want to it.
<Tab title={<span className="text-dark-blue">Website</span>}>

The problem with your current approach is that NextUI is adding the class you've given it to an element above the one that sets the text color by default, so your text color style is overridden.  Check out this documentation to get a better understanding of how it works.
